# How to remove the java standard library from a gradle project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management, lejos-nxj

**How can one make Gradle not include the Java standard library as a dependency to IntelliJ IDEA project?**

I am using IntelliJ and every time I `Refresh all Gradle projects`:

[image]

IntelliJ adds the Java standard library back to the project as an external dependency:

[image]

So I have to manually remove it every single time:

[image]

## Things I tried that didn't work out

- fiddling with the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatability` properties...
- applying the `idea` plugin to Gradle and setting `idea.project.jdkName` to `null`.

## Background

- I'm writing a program for the [Lego NXT Brick](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/NXT-Intelligent-Brick-9841)
- I'm using [Lejos](http://www.lejos.org/) so I can write the program in Java
- [Lejos' "standard library"](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/api/index.html) for the Lego brick is only a fraction of the actual Java standard library....(because of memory constraints?)
- Lejos provides a JAR file that contains all the classes of their standard library to assist in programming. I've added this JAR as a dependency of the project.
- Gradle also (implicitly?) adds the actual java standard library as a dependency to the project, which obscures Lejos' standard library classes since they use the same names...

P.S. at least this is what I think is happening....please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: It seems to be JME. Try to download and install the JME-SDK and use that as your "JDK".

Comment: A bit late... but I had a similar need and I managed to remove the JDK entry with a custom plugin: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4412552552722-Remove-JRE-entry-from-External-Library-for-Android-Studio-project (it is for Android Studio but I guess it should work for IntelliJ IDEA as well).

Answer (score -3):

You better create a user variable like %JAVAHOME% in enivronment variables and give it in path in the system variables.
use 1.7 in javahome and 1.8 in javahomeb
when you want 1.8 just rename the variable

Comment: He doesn't want either 1.7 or 1.8. You don't appear to have read the question.