# How to replace JDK standard library with a custom library in Gradle "compile" task?

Tags: java, gradle, compilation, java-me

I'm building a [Java Micro Edition](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/overview/index.html) (ME) application which comes with it's own standard library ([Cinterion Mobility Toolkit](https://developer.gemalto.com/documentation/cinterion%C2%AE-concept-board-tools-documentation)). When compiling my application class files with Gradle, I would like to replace JDK standard library with my own set of JAR files.

Most likely I'll have to write a custom Gradle plugin (extending Gradle Java plugin) but any suggestion is welcome.

P.S. There is a similar question [How to remove the java standard library from a gradle project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786992/how-to-remove-the-java-standard-library-from-a-gradle-project) - but that is also missing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following snipped did the trick:

```
compileJava {
  options.bootstrapClasspath = fileTree("/path/to/cinterion/wtk/home") {
    include 'lib/*.jar'
    include 'resources/*.jar'
  }
}
```

Obviously, replace `"/path/to/cinterion/wtk/home"` with your own path.